# What is the best way to represent similar inputs for rules in a relational database?

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database, rule-engine

I am designing a rules database, which takes a number of inputs and determines the appropriate output.

There is a set of ~20 input types that are very similar (can be represented with Id, Value) which all drive a set ~20 output types. Each input type has a number of possible values. Each output type has a number of possible values as well.

An example rule would be `InputTypeA + InputTypeB determines OutputTypeA` or `InputTypeA determines OutputTypeB`. `n` input types can drive an output, but currently the maximum number is 3.

1. What is the best way to store the input values? I am considering either:

- Storing in one table, with a `InputType` table FK'd to determine the type of the input value (they will all be strings from a db type perspective).
- Storing each input type in a seperate table.

2. How can I represent the relationships? I could have a separate table for each relationship, but this system should be as flexible as possible. I'm concerned that will be a large number of tables, and make it difficult to add new rules.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please provide sample input, and sample expected results.  Your description of this problem seems very detailed, but still without those elements it would be hard to come up with a solution that matches your need.

Answer (score 0):

I would think of this as 3 major concepts.

**Condition**: what needs to be true for a rule to fire?
**Rule**: when a rule fires, which results are true?
**Result**: which outputs fire, and with which values?

Conditions are modelled as one or more inputs with their values (your example uses InputTypeA + InputTypeB so I assume a rule has one or more qualifying inputs).

Results are modelled as one or more output, with their values.

Specifically:

```
Condition
-----------
ID
RuleID
InputType
InputValue

Rule
----
ID

Result
-------
ID
RuleID
OutputType
OutputValue
```

If there is more logic to input types and output types, you can create a lookup table with a foreign key relationship.

Example might be:

Condition

```
ID RuleID InputType         InputValue
1       1 DrivingIn30zone            1
2       1 CurrentSpeed              40

Rule

ID   Name
1    Don't break the speed limit

Result
ID    RuleID    OutputType    OutputValue
1.         1     SetSpeed              29
```

You would then search for conditions which match your current input values to see what the output states are: